# How do I tie my Model classes with an existing database in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've written my classes in the Models folder and I already have a database with data in SQL Express. What I want to do is just tie the two together. How do I do this? All I have seen is Code First (class creates database/tables) but that's not what I want.

Comment: Actually, Code First *is* what you want, provided they are relatively compatible. You can use DataAnnotations and/or the Fluent Configuration to map things, and be sure to set your Context not to try to recreate a Db, and you'd be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Barber pointed out in his comment, EF with Code First is the way to go, provided the classes in your modell are structurally close if not identical to the tables in your database. Even if the structure is not that compatible current versions of EF can help you a lot with the use of things like views and stored procedures.

Scott Guthrie has an excellent [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx) that should get you started.